# wxWidgets SetBackgroundStyle() shows gtk_widget_set_colormap: assertion gtk_widget_get_realized()failed

Tags: wxwidgets

Hi i tried to create transparent window using

`SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_TRANSPARENT)`

but the window created with black background and shows assert message

> "gtk_widget_set_colormap: assertion gtk_widget_get_realized()failed"

How can i correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#af14f8fd2ed2d30a9bbb5d4f9fd6594ec) you need to call `SetBackgroundStyle()` before creating the window.

Also try calling `IsTransparentBackgroundSupported()` to check if this functionality is supported at all under your system.

Comment: First of all Thankyou for your comment, But  i was followed the documentation, i called  SetBackgroundStyle() before creating the window and IsTransparentBackgroundSupported() function also return true.Then also i have same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it doesn't work then. Try running the `erase` or `shaped` wxWidgets samples, which use this style as well, if they don't work neither, please [open a ticket](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket) with all the details about your system, in particular the GTK+ version.